# Testing the computer DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I'm trying to make a function which tests if the computer time format is **12h** or **24h**. Currently I have this function:

```
string format = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");

if (format == "AM" || format == "PM")
{
    //12h
}
else
{
    //24h
}
```

But there is a problem with this function. If I change the format to **12h** and I run the app for the first time, it will tell me that the format is **24h** (which was before). And after I run it again, it will tell me that the format is **12h**. The problem is that the app tells me the correct answer after the second run. I need a function which will test correctly won the fist run, not the second one.

The function will be in `Form1_Load` for testing on form load.

Comment: You're not sure of the culture settings, and yet you're sure that AM and PM are the only possible 12 hour designators? What will you do with the *result* of this test - how well your program work differently? Perhaps we could suggest a better overall solution...

Comment: On my settings (it-IT) I haven't any 'tt' thus the format string is empty.

Comment: I try this on a label, and if the 12h format is on, will display AM or PM, but if the 24h format is on, will dispplay nothing !

Comment: I try with the English (United State) format. Now I realise that I need a better function for testing the format ! You on IT have the 24h format !

Comment: How about checking `ShortTimePattern` of `DateTimeFormatInfo` of the current culture, if it has `h` or `H` (24 hr)

Answer (score 0):

CultureInfo should support the 24 hour boolean, but thats not the case.
However this will tell you if the system is displaying the am/pm symbol:

```
bool is12hr =  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.Contains("t");
```

Comment: If the 12h format is on, will display true, else false. But it work only after secound running. Like my function ! I display the result on a label !

Comment: This seems a bit dangerous to me. You should explain why you are only looking for a single character "t" and why this is sufficient.